# Creating a Random Garden Layout in Illustrator, Photoshop

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, layout

How can I create a random layout, like the one in this garden plan, in Illustrator, Photoshop, or any other app? The average size of a patch is around 1-2 meters. I would like to add different plants for the random patches, but I don't want to deal with drawing or constructing the patches myself.

[image]

Comment: You may get a drawing program to scatter predrawn items  to the layout area. At least Inkscape has such tool. It allows also some primitive rules to be applied such as size and rotation variations and avoiding inserting too much in the same place. But drawing programs know nothing of plants. To be useful the program should know what can be seen between and behind others and which species cannot stand each other or need so different conditions that they cannot be close each other. I guess scattering various splashes around the artboard is useless  A programmer-gardener team may write a script.

Comment: (continued) but the programmer must be able to extract quite a high pile of plant placement rules from the gardener and the gardener must tolerate a person who seemingly was born without  any common sense and ability to think by himself. Actually his computer  has that property, but the programmer is the vicarious sufferer.

Comment: Isn't making a *random* garden *plan* self-contradictory? If the shapes doesn't matter why not just put your plants in random places on site? But perhaps it's just the visual *look* of the pattern you want? Anyway, coding something like that would take way longer than drawing the shapes manually, so if you're just making one or a few you are better off just getting started drawing.